# How to check refresh page event in angular 8 and show a dialog asking user to Reload or cancel action

Tags: javascript, angular

I implement a registration component. When the form is dirty and the user hit F5/refresh page, I want to catch this event and show a dialog asking user to chose between reload or cancel the action. (like the image in the link)

https://files.gitter.im/angular/angular/wLcy/image.png

I did research and know about `onbeforeunload` but I cannot custom the dialog, only `leave` or `cancel` option in the dialog.
For the UX design, the dialog should be asking about reload/cancel. So I'm looking for a solution that fixes the problem.

Comment: Do you want Custom button label or custom message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In angular, you can achieve it using `HostListener` and `onbeforeunload` event.
Follow the example [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-how-keep-user-from-lost-his-data-by-accidentally-leaving-the-page-before-submit-4eeb74420f0d) which explains, the exact answer of your question.